# How can I see a list of all SharePoint sites (O365) and who has what permissions to each site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

We have SharePoint online (O365) and we'd like to see a list of all sites and what users or groups have what permissions for each site. I have searched for answers to this, but I've come up empty or with scripts and commands that don't do what I need.

Before I began this search I thought that certainly this is something that's needed by many, and therefore the solution would be easily found. Now I'm thinking that there either is no solution or I'm the only one in the world that needs this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Jono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one bad thing the cloud inherited from the on-prem SharePoint.  this function doesn't exist out of the box.  You have to create something custom to get this functionality, or use a third party tool.

SharePoint Document Toolkit and ShareGate are nice tools at a reasonable price that can give you this insight.  There other other tools from AvePoint, Metalogix, and some other smaller vendors out there you can check out as well.

In O365 in the portal there is a report that will give you all the sites - but not user permissions.

Comment: And there is a DeliverPoint app from Lightning Tools

Comment: Thanks, Jesus and Eric, for your responses. I'll take a look at those tools you mentioned. Perhaps in the future, Microsoft will provide built-in tools that will provide this type of information. As I said in my original question, it seems many people would need it.

Comment: Just wondering, since its been almost 4 years, if this answer is still applicable?

Comment: The new admin portal will show all sites now, but there is no unified output regarding site and library permission - you have to pull those via API or still use a 3rd party tool